# Multiple tooltips at one time?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to show several tooltips at one time for two series in area plot?

Like here:

[image]

Comment: How many mice do you have?  Use [labels](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels).

Answer (score 1):

Defaulty it is not supported, but you can add extra div (in your html website) which is positioned absolutely. Then catch [mouse over](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) / [out](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut) event on point and show / hide / fill data this div.

Comment: how can I get y-coordinates of other points for given x coordinate in that event?

Comment: In the this object, you have referens to many parameters, so use console.log(this) and run any console (like developer tools in chroe). You will see all avaialble elements.